# Using Applescript to align / distribute objects in PowerPoint

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

I am trying to write an Applescript to distribute / align objects on a PowerPoint slide. So far I managed to address the selected objects. But I can't figure out a way how to then distribute / align them.

Here's what I have so far:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
set theShapeRange to shape range of selection of active window
distribute shapes with properties
{distribute type:distribute horizontally}
end tell
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2016, you do the following:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    set theShapeRange to shape range of selection of active window
    distribute theShapeRange distribute type distribute vertically without relative to slide
end tell
```

Alignment has similar syntax (`align theShapeRange align type align lefts`).

The Dictionary entry for `distribute` indicates that the `without relative to slide` parameter is optional, but the script throws an error if I omit that. The Dictionary actually lists the parameter as `relative to slide <boolean>`, but Script Editor swapped it for the other format. The `align` command didn't have that issue (i.e., I could omit the optional last parameter).